# Use sqlite with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5

I'm on ubuntu

```
#include <sqlite3.h>    /* sqlite3 */


void prog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("/home/profile.sqlite", &db);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",
                sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);    
     }
}
```

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: @eyllanesc ubuntu and no

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the sqlite library in linux (ubuntu) you must install the following library:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Then you can add it to your .pro file with the following statement:

```
LIBS += -lsqlite3
```

Qt also provides the `QtSql` module that manages several databases, including `sqlite`, I recommend you read the following about it:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html
- https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/libqt5sql5-sqlite/
- https://katecpp.wordpress.com/2015/08/28/sqlite-with-qt/